# Hungarian BibLaTeX journal citation

Tags: biblatex, languages

How to make BibLaTeX print

> "27. évf. 1. sz. pp. 5-23"

instead of

> "vol. 27, no. 1, pp. 5-23"

?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern, filecontents}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zarandy_art_temdesign,
    author = {Zarándy, Ákos},
    title = {The art of {CNN} template design},
    journal = {International Journal of Circuit Theory and Applications},
    volume = {27},
    number = {1},
    publisher = {John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.},
    issn = {1097-007X},
    url = {http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~lazar/cnn/SegedFileok/ZA_TemplTervArt.pdf},
    urldate = {2014-04-22},
    pages = {5--23},
    year = {1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{zarandy_art_temdesign}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My `magyar.lbx` contains, among other things

```
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{
% ...
page         = {{oldal}{p\adddot}},
pages        = {{oldalak}{pp\adddot}},
volume       = {{évfolyam}{évf\adddot}},
volumes      = {{évfolyam}{évf\adddot}},
number       = {{szám}{sz\adddot}},
}
```

so the strings are already there but in incorrect order with the numbers.

Comment: `Package biblatex Warning: Language 'magyar' not supported.`

Comment: @egreg I know, that's the unfortunate situation I'm trying to change. https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/latex-magyar-contrib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`biblatex-ieee`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) package was recently [updated](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/40#event-1798043494) to support the Hungarian language, so shortly there will be no need for extra code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of `biblatex-ieee` you can just redefine the field format as

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace\bibstring{volume}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace\bibstring{jourvol}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{#1\adddot\addnbspace\bibstring{number}}
```

But even more recent versions (>= 1.3) will also have Hungarian support available out of the box (that might only be really usable once `biblatex`'s Hungarian support is released, see [Hungarian with LuaLaTex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416627/35864)).

The solution for older versions can be found in the edit history.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern, filecontents}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zarandy_art_temdesign,
    author = {Zarándy, Ákos},
    title = {The art of {CNN} template design},
    journal = {International Journal of Circuit Theory and Applications},
    volume = {27},
    number = {1},
    publisher = {John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.},
    issn = {1097-007X},
    url = {http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~lazar/cnn/SegedFileok/ZA_TemplTervArt.pdf},
    urldate = {2014-04-22},
    pages = {5--23},
    year = {1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace\bibstring{volume}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace\bibstring{jourvol}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{#1\adddot\addnbspace\bibstring{number}}

\begin{document}
\cite{zarandy_art_temdesign}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to get rid of the comma after `vol.` and `no.`? How can I make this code work in the lbx file?

Comment: @marczellm Make the `\newunit` after `\bibstring{volume}%` into `\addspace`. Normally this kind of modification is not applied in an `.lbx` file but in the document itself. You could include the above redefinitions in the `\DeclareBibliographyExtras` section, but this will tie your `.lbx` file to `biblatex-ieee`.