# Hungarian BibLaTeX online citation

Tags: biblatex, languages, hungarian

How to make BibLaTeX print

> Elérhető: http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~lazar/cnn/SegedFileok/ZA_TemplTervArt.pdf (elérés dátuma 2014. 04. 22.).

instead of

> Available: http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~lazar/cnn/SegedFileok/ZA_TemplTervArt.pdf (visited on 04/22/2014).

?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern, filecontents}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zarandy_art_temdesign,
    author = {Zarándy, Ákos},
    title = {The art of {CNN} template design},
    journal = {International Journal of Circuit Theory and Applications},
    volume = {27},
    number = {1},
    publisher = {John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.},
    issn = {1097-007X},
    url = {http://digitus.itk.ppke.hu/~lazar/cnn/SegedFileok/ZA_TemplTervArt.pdf},
    urldate = {2014-04-22},
    pages = {5--23},
    year = {1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{zarandy_art_temdesign}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The relevant bibstrings are `url` and `urlseen`. Or is there any other problem? (I assume you know how to deal with bibstrings, because of [this question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218858/35864).) Of course the date format is another matter.

Comment: @moewe Oh, I didn't think `url` is the bibstring I'm looking for. Thank you. So how to format the date?

Comment: Have a look at the `mkbibdatelong` and `mkbibdateshort` macros found in the `.lbx` files (`english.lbx` and `german.lbx` for example, the latter of the two might even contain the definition you want).

Comment: Related (just for the link): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416627/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428749/35864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UPDATE

The next version of `biblatex` (3.12, no release date announced yet as of August 2018) will come with built-in Hungarian support. If you have this or a later version, you do not need to do anything else.

---

#### PREVIOUS

Put this in the `magyar.lbx` file:

```
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    % ...
    url          = {{Elérhető}{Elérhető}},
    urlfrom      = {{elérhető}{elérhető}},
    urlseen      = {{elérés dátuma}{elérés dátuma}},
}

\DeclareBibliographyExtras{
    % ...
    \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{\stripzeros{#1}\adddot}%
    \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{% suppose that all fields are defined, until a bug pops up
        \mkbibordinal{\thefield{#1}}%
        \space%
        \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
        \nobreakspace%
        \mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
    }
    \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{% suppose that all fields are defined, until a bug pops up
        \mkbibordinal{\thefield{#1}}%
        \space%
        \mkbibordinal{\thefield{#2}}%
        \nobreakspace%
        \mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I ran into the problem of not having biblatex in hungarian. I saw in another post that you have started making the `magyar.lbx`. Are you planning on making a pull request to biblatex? If not everything is done, I'd appreciate if we could communicate, in say email, about this!

Comment: @fbence I have uploaded it to https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/latex-magyar-contrib/src but I don't know if it's complete enough to be included in biblatex.

Comment: I actually found some errors, so probably not yet, but, if you're interested, I'd be happy to help to follow it through to including in biblatex.

Comment: @fbence yes we should do this.

Comment: Great, lets move this to email (and hungarian): fbence elte hu.

Comment: You should probably update your answer with today's developments :)

Comment: Just to add the same disclaimer as below https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446190/35864: `biblatex` 3.12 has not been released yet and it will likely take some time until it will be released. The `dev` branch on GitHub https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/dev/ has Hungarian support merged, but that can't be run out of the box (it needs to be installed with the install script) and needs a dev version of Biber as well.

Comment: Thank you, I can't even promise it will be called 3.12, but it is quite likely ...