# Hungarian with LuaLaTex and biber

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber, hungarian

I am having trouble with getting `LuaLaTex` with `biber` working in Hungarian. I have `texlive-full` install on an Ubuntu 16.04 and I did not have this issue with a previous install. I'm providing below an mwe, the output and warnings given by lualatex. How can I fix this?

The mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{magyar}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,sorting=none,backend=biber,maxnames=10,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{text.bib}

\begin{document}

Próba \cite{graphtheory,barabasi2016network,king2002home,linklater2000adaptive,moehlman1998feral,moehlman2002equids}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `bib` file:

```
@book{graphtheory,
  title={Graph theory},
  author={Bondy, John Adrian and Murty, Uppaluri Siva Ramachandra},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Springer}
}


@article{king2002home,
  title={Home range and habitat use of free-ranging Przewalski horses at Hustai National Park, Mongolia},
  author={King, SRB},
  journal={Applied Animal Behaviour Science},
  volume={78},
  number={2},
  pages={103--113},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Output:

[image]

Errors:

```
Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'magyar'.
(csquotes)                Using fallback style on input line 9.


Package biblatex Warning: Language 'magyar' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using fallback language 'english' on input line 9.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./mwe_magyar.aux
Language magyar not found in language.dat.lua)
Language magyar not found in language.dat.lua (./mwe_magyar.bbl)(load luc: /hom
e/fbence/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-regula
r.luc)(load luc: /home/fbence/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts
/otl/lmroman12-bold.luc)

Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'and' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'graphtheory' on input line 13.


Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'jourvol' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'king2002home' on input line 13.


Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'number' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'king2002home' on input line 13.


Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'pages' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'king2002home' on input line 13.
```

Comment: This is simple. `biblatex` does not speak Hungarian, neither as `magyar` nor `hungarian`. If you want Hungarian support, you will have to write it yourself [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864). The `biblatex` maintainers will be very happy to accept pull requests that implement Hungarian support at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pulls, if you want to contribute what you come up with.

Comment: The `Package biblatex Warning: Language 'magyar' not supported.` warning is the giveaway. The question marks are caused by `csquotes` inability to speak Hungarian, `Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'magyar'.`, see [quotation mark (quotation sign) xelatex + polyglossia + csquotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864)

Comment: That's very interesting, I'm pretty sure, that I had previously made a hungarian document with biblatex ... Is there a way to have a Hungarian document with citations in English as a quick fix? I will look at making a Hungarian localization for biblatex.

Comment: Add `language=english` to your `biblatex` loading options.

Comment: Mhh, `language=english` doesn't work. `polyglossia` and `biblatex` don't work together that well. Could you use `babel`? With `babel` `biblatex` automatically falls back to English and only warns about this.

Comment: I downloaded this as a solution: https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/latex-magyar-contrib, and tried to contact the author about the status of this making it into texlive. Although I am now really confused how my other document worked with hungarian ... Anyway, it's kinda solved, thanks!

Comment: Well, it can't have worked in Hungarian with the official sources. It might have fallen back to English if you used `babel`. Or you might have had a local Hungarian localisation file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Edit*: Following this question **Hungarian support has been implemented in version 3.12 of `biblatex`** (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/717, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/780).
>   So if you need support for Hungarian today, this should be as simple as making sure that you have an up to date version of `biblatex`.
>
> Do note that the Hungarian localisation module is a bit special since the `.lbx` files are ill-equipped to deal with some features of non-Germanic languages. So double check the output carefully and read the warnings in the documentation and the `.log` file.
>
> In general of course, `bibatex` can only implement localisations for a language if someone knowledgable in that language comes along and offers their help as was the case here.
>
> The answer below is left for historical purposes.

At the moment `biblatex` has no support for Hungarian. This is what `biblatex` tries to tell you with

> ```
> Package biblatex Warning: Language 'magyar' not supported.
> ```

If you use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`, `biblatex` will fall back to English, with `polyglossia` (for which localisation with `biblatex` is a bit shaky in general) you will get bold labels instead.

Comment: You should probably update your answer with today's developments :)